# How to call PHP function within HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML page fully functional and based on Twitter Bootstrap.

In order to add a contact form (in that case within a modal window), I implemented a bit of PHP code to my file. 
After having saved my file as index.php instead of index.html, for the PHP to be interpreted on the server, only the background appears, all content vanished.

Beginning of my code including the problematic PHP part before the main div starts :

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="fr">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>Manena.fr | Originaux, uniques et faits main, des cadeaux pour toutes les occasions</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="./css/custom.css"rel="stylesheet" >
            <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->

            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paprika" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>

        <?php 

            include('success.php');

            if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['nom']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

            if(!empty($_POST['nom']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
                $destinataire = "contact@site.com";
                $sujet = "Demande de contact";
                $message .= "Nom : ".$_POST['nom']."\r\n";
                $message .= "Adresse email : ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
                $message .= "Message : ".$_POST['message']."\r\n";
                $entete = 'From: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n".
                'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n".
                'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

            if (mail($destinataire,$sujet,$message,$entete)){
                showSuccess();
                } else {

                echo "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'envoi du formulaire par email";

                }
            }
            }
        ?>

HTML CODE

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Modal Privacy-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#modalPrivacy").click(function(event){
        $("#modalPrivacy2").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Modal Contact-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#modalContact").click(function(event){
        $("#modalContact2").modal('show');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is : What prevents my page form displaying and eventually, how to fix it ?

For complementary info, here is the content of my success.php file (used to close the current modal and display a new one with a success message) :

```
<?php function showSuccess() {
    echo'<script>$("#modalContact2").modal('hide');</script>'
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#modalSuccess").modal('show');
        });
    </script>'
} ?>
```

Comment: I don't see any bootstrap script file mentioned in your header.

Comment: Do you see any PHP error? Try enabling PHP error reporting.

Comment: most probably there is some kind of php error/warning. Put `display_errors(1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your page (inside php tags ofcourse). And let us know what you see

Comment: @giorgio I added display_errors(1); and error_reporting(E_ALL); right between <?php and include('success.php'); and no error showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your `success.php` file has wrong quotes, like so:

> echo '`<script type="text/javascript">`
>
> $("#modalContact2").modal(\'hide\');
>
> $("#modalSuccess").modal(\'show\');
>
> `</script>'`

You are using single quotes inside echo for .modal('show'). These single quotes end the echo statement. Escape these quotes like .modal(\'show\').

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it will probably be useful later, but it didn't solve my current display issue...

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code. you have some js errors for sure

```
function showSuccess() 
            {
                echo "<script>$('#modalContact2').modal('hide');</script>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        $('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
                      </script>";
            }
```

You placed }); after $('#modalSuccess').modal('show'); line which is only closing braces but not opening. I removed that.I checked it with alert and its working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer joins the one of myusuf, it will certainely help for the modal, but my page still doesn't display.

Comment: I think you have js issues. Please check using firebug or similar tools to identify js issues

Comment: effectively i get $ is not defined on line 27 which corresponds to <script>$('#modalContact2').modal('hide');</script><script type='text/javascript'> in the success.php

Comment: It means jquery is not included in this page or jquery may be conflicting with mootools or other javascript libraries

Comment: In case of conflicts refer [avoid-conflicts-other-libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I solved my problem through using another technique than calling a modal. But your help has been useful to me !

Answer (score 0):

replace your success.php code with this

function showSuccess() {

```
echo '<script>$("#modalContact2").modal(\'hide\');</script>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modalSuccess").modal(\'show\');
    });
</script>';
```

}

Hope your main file ext is php not html. please verify it.

Comment: Thanks for posting, as precised in the original post, my file is obviously index.php and not index.html.